# Bash not recognizing npm and node when running scripts

Tags: window, git-bash

I have a weird issue with git bash regarding node and npm. 
I used `nvm for windows` before and I taught that might be the issue, but even after installing node and npm without nvm, git bash won't recognize when running scripts that use npm or node.

When using bash without running scripts:

`which npm // -> /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm`

`which node // -> /c/Program Files/nodejs/node`

`node -v // -> v6.14.0`

But when running scripts that use npm or node (from package.json for example), I get the following errors:

`'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

`'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Why bash is not recognizing the commands?

Comment: what output you get if you do `which node` inside the scripts that use `node`?

Comment: the problem is with PATH env variable being not set or overwritten in git bash subshell. try echoing PATH

Comment: and/or make sure the `Program Files/nodejs` is IN the path used by git bash shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not which one of these fixed the issue, but here is what I did:

1. Edit the `PATH` in windows so node will be the first entry.
2. Call `nvm use` inside bash and not cmd/powershell.